# Problem involving a quadratic

Tags: quadratics

This is the equation : $mx^2-(4m-1)x+3m-2=0 $

We are asked to find a relationship between the roots that doesn't involve the 'm' parameter. Therefore, I thought the key to achieving this was making use of Vieta's formulas, but nothing useful came out no matter how much I played with the equations .

Can someone point me to the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\qquad\qquad r+s &=& 4-1/m\\
r\,*\,s &=& 3-2/m\\
\hline \\
\Rightarrow\ 2(r+s)-r*s &=& \ \ldots\qquad \text{by eliminating}\,\ 1/m
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: That was really stupid of me, not noticing such a trivial trick. Thanks a lot

Comment: @victor We've all overlooked simple things. When that occurs, I recommend performing some meta-reflection to attempt to understand the source of the oversight. E.g. above, perhaps it was not obvious that one could eliminate the *expression* $\,1/m\,$ just like one can eliminate a *variable*.  If you constantly perform such meta-level reflection, it can go a long way towards strengthening your problem-solving skills.

Comment: That's perfectly true Mr. Dubuque, thanks a lot for your extremely useful input !

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the two roots of the given quadratic equation. Vieta's formulas give that 
\begin{align}
x_1+x_2 &= \frac{4m-1}{m},\\
x_1x_2 &= \frac{3m-2}{m}.
\end{align}
Multiplying the first equation by $2m$ and the second equation by $m$ gives
\begin{align}
2m(x_1+x_2) &= 8m-2,\\
mx_1x_2 &= 3m-2.
\end{align}
Subtracting the second equation from the first gives that 
\begin{equation}
m(2(x_1+x_2)-x_1x_2) = 5m.
\end{equation}
Therefore the $m$ cancels, leaving
\begin{equation}
2(x_1+x_2)-x_1x_2 = 5.
\end{equation}